# Suggest Tags for StackOverflow Questions

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, tags

It'd be nice to be able to suggest tags for other people's questions as they are often mis-tagged.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Comments only require 50 reputation and are sufficient for suggesting tag changes. If you don't inspire the author to fix the tags, then someone else who has at least 500 reputation can subsequently fix the tags according to your comments. There isn't really any need for a system outside of comments.

Comment: Sounds good, I'll leave some comments on those posts then. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Just get to 500 rep and you can retag them.

Comment: For reference, the complete list of things you can do and how much rep you need to do them is in the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Answer (score 2):

Something like the way [delicious.com](http://delicious.com) do it would be great.